# Remote validation Json MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to validate an input field value from user before the form is submitted.
I have created an action in my custom controller and decorated the field with Month.

```
[Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:Y}")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
        [Display(Name = "Month")]
        [Remote("IsvalidMonth", "Objectives", AdditionalFields = "UserID,SalesObjectiveID", ErrorMessage = "Month already existing")]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM-yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Month { get; set; }
```

And my validation is:

```
public JsonResult IsvalidMonth(DateTime Month, int? SalesObjectiveID, int? UserID)
        {
            var monthexist = _context.TBL_SalesObjective.Where(x => x.Month == Month && x.SalesObjectiveID == SalesObjectiveID && x.UserID == UserID).FirstOrDefault().Month;

            return Json(!monthexist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

but i cant use !monthexist because The opperator ! cannot be applied.

How can i do validation in Monht?

Comment: I think your validation should be `var monthexist = _context.TBL_SalesObjective.Any(x => x.Month == Month && x.SalesObjectiveID == SalesObjectiveID && x.UserID == UserID);` This will return a boolean and then you can apply a '!' operator.

Comment: okey, it works!!.. but the validation doesnt work, not passes in the jsonREsult... i make a breakpoint and nothing happens @PriyankPanchal

Answer (score 0):

The '!' operator can be used with boolean, here since you are doing `.FirstOrDefault().Month` which is not a boolean, you cannot use '!' operator.

Please try the below code in your `IsvalidMonth()` method

```
var monthexist = _context.TBL_SalesObjective.Any(x => x.Month == Month && x.SalesObjectiveID == SalesObjectiveID && x.UserID == UserID);
```

Comment: okey, it works!!.. but the validation doesnt work, not passes in the jsonREsult... i make a breakpoint there and nothing happens...

Comment: Is it hitting your `IsvalidMonth()` method? @PedroSantos

Comment: Is `UserID` & `SalesObjectiveID` present in the same model class as Month? Also, in `IsvalidMonth()` try making `DateTime` to `DateTime?` Don't know any other reason why it would not work.